# AutoSPInstaller alternatives for setting up SharePoint 2019 farm?

Tags: 2019, farm-setup, autospinstaller

In the past we often used [AutoSPInstaller](https://github.com/brianlala/AutoSPInstaller) to set up SharePoint farms which worked quite well.

Recently I heard the recommendation to stop using it since it is not being actively developed anymore. (?)

Which alternative do you use for setting up your on-prem farms?

Comment: Despite the close-votes flowing in I appreciate the feedback so far.

Answer (score 2):

I have set up several SharePoint 2019 farms with AutoSPInstaller and everything worked well. I can confirm this bug, which can easily be resolved by a simple reboot:  [Script halted when creating root site collection in SP2019 #38](https://github.com/brianlala/AutoSPInstaller/issues/38)

You can see a [bunch of code commits related to SharePoint 2019](https://github.com/brianlala/AutoSPInstaller/commits/master) in the Github-Repository. The Github Root-Page also notes SP2010-2019 as supported versions.

I think the silence about AutoSPInstaller is mostly because it has become rock-stable over time. The changes from SharePoint 2016 (which introduced MinRoles) to SharePoint 2019 are very limited, so there was not so much to change for AutoSPInstaller-Developers.

My recommendation: Continue to use AutoSPInstaller, as it solves most of the installation hassle out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to what @MHeld answered.

AutoSPInstaller is going to be supported in SP 2019. However, since you also wanted to know the alternatives to it, you can checkout [SharePointDsc](https://github.com/PowerShell/SharePointDsc). It is a powershell module using which you can manage the farm. It also supports SP 2019 as well.

You can checkout this blog on- [How to Get Started with SharePointDSC](https://nikcharlebois.com/how-to-get-started-with-sharepointdsc/)

There is also a converter available to [migrate AutoSPInstaller to SharePointDSC](https://andikrueger.wordpress.com/2018/03/08/autospinstaller-xml-to-sharepointdsc-converter-preview/) which you can use for your existing scripts